# Sorted is sorting numbers in the wrong direction?

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
marketUSDC = {"LTC":USDC_LTC,"BCHABC":USDC_BCHABC}
[key for (key, value) in sorted(marketUSDC.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

USDC_LTC and USDC_BCHABC each return a numerical price from an API, which are 60.80000000 and 153.00000000, respectively. The problem is that the second line should be returning [LTC, BCHABC] but it's returning [BCHABC, LTC]. How can I fix this problem such that it's sorted as it should be, from low to high? I understand I could just reverse it, but that would break the code for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

use `sorted(variable, reverse=True)`, so that it will be the reverse order. [SOURCE](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html?highlight=sort#ascending-and-descending)